# Удаление элемента из Vec с проверкой

Tags: rust

**Требуется:** удалить элемент из **Vec** с возвратом результата. Существует функция remove в Vec, но она не возвращяет Option в случае не успеха, а заставляет программу падать.

**Описание:** `pub fn remove(&mut self, index: usize) -> T {`

**Пример:**

```
fn main() {
    let mut array = vec![1024, 2048, 1024*9];

    println!("{:?}", array.remove(1)); // <- 2048
    println!("{:?}", array.remove(1)); // <- 9216

    //PANIC
    println!("{:?}", array.remove(1)); // <- assertion failed: index < len

    println!("Array {:?}", array);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Решение**, самый оптимальный вариант реализовать крейт.

*//FILE MOD*

```
use std::ptr;

pub trait SafeRemoveVec<T> {
    fn safe_remove(&mut self, index: usize) -> Option<T>;
}


impl<T> SafeRemoveVec<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn safe_remove(&mut self, index: usize) -> Option<T> { //COPY-PASTE, RM FOR VEC, AND ADD OPTION
        let len = self.len(); 
        if index >= len {
            return None;
        }
        unsafe {
            // infallible
            let ret;
            {
                // the place we are taking from.
                let ptr = self.as_mut_ptr().offset(index as isize);
                // copy it out, unsafely having a copy of the value on
                // the stack and in the vector at the same time.
                ret = ptr::read(ptr);

                // Shift everything down to fill in that spot.
                ptr::copy(ptr.offset(1), ptr, len - index - 1);
            }
            self.set_len(len - 1);
            Some(ret)
        }
    }
}
```

**Использование:**

```
use SafeVec::Remove::SafeRemoveVec;
fn main() {
    let mut vec = vec![0i8, 120i8];

    println!("{:?}", vec.safe_remove(1));
    println!("{:?}", vec.safe_remove(1));
    println!("{:?}", vec.safe_remove(0));
    println!("{:?}", vec.safe_remove(0));
}
```

**Вывод:**

```
Some(120)
None
Some(0)
None
```

**Запуск:** https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=bcd777b4de6cd646b3c7eae1f80e1baa&version=stable

Comment: Зачем копировать код `remove` из стандартной библиотеки? `if index < self.len() {Some(self.remove(index))} else {None}`. Ассемблерный код получается один и тот же: https://godbolt.org/g/rzJDxc Что не удивительно - код `Vec<T>` полиморфный, так что компилируется в том крейте где используется.

Comment: "if index < self.len() {Some(self.remove(index))} else {None}" Если взглянете внимательно то https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/src/alloc/vec.rs.html#770-789  сравнение зашито в remove. Тоесть вы делаете два раза сравнение?? Я сделал функцию которая в случае сравнения которое зашито в remove будет возвращять None

Comment: А так, за дизасемблирование спасибо. вижу что немного не прав в этом случае. Но с Option удобнее, чем вешать вечные if, разве не в этом идеи раста?

Comment: Если пытаемся удалить что-то за пределами массива, то у нас скорее баг, а не `None`.

Comment: Я попробовал свой крейт на предмет выхода за пределы. Все нормально let mut array = vec![1024, 2048, 1024*9];
    
    println!("{:?}", array.safe_remove(1));
    println!("{:?}", array.safe_remove(1));

    //PANIC
    println!("{:?}", array.safe_remove(1));
    println!("{:?}", array.safe_remove(999));
    println!("{:?}", array.safe_remove(0));  Some(2048)
Some(9216)
None
None
Some(1024)
Array []

Comment: Я говорил про то, почему стандартная библиотека не реализует `safe_remove()`. Если программа пытается удалить значение за концом массива, например по индексу `0xFFFF_FFFF`, то скорее всего в программе баг, и использование `safe_remove()` просто перенесёт момент падения программы в место удалённое от причины бага, на какой-нибудь `opt.unwrap()`. Но, конечно, должны быть и случаи, когда использование `safe_remove()` оправданно.

Comment: А я так и не понял, почему ассемблерных код один и тот же. Ведь там действительно два if, в функции и выше. Или тут работают оптимизации компилятора? И как мне теперь писать код? Как понять, где копировать код для более быстрой работы, а где за меня всё решит компилятор?

Comment: Смотри, раньше я этого не знал но!.  https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec.rs.html#877-896  вот код официальной функции Remove. Заметил там assert!(index < len); ?, вот! Я не помню как звучит это официально, но assert реализован на уровне компилятора и идет как нейки отладочник, в случае он может паниковать, я думаю что компилятор может догадатся когда проверять выход за предел, а когда ты это делаешь выше.

Answer (score -1):

Индексация ВСЕГДА начинается с нуля, ты удаляешь второй элемент вектора (индекс 1) вот тут: println!("{:?}", array.remove(1)); // <- 9216

```
fn main() {
    let mut array = vec![1024, 2048, 1024*9];

    println!("{:?}", array.remove(1)); // <- 2048
    println!("{:?}", array.remove(1)); // <- 9216

    let a = array[0];
    println!("{:?}", array.remove(0)); // <-   index = len
    //теперь данные в 'a' 
    println!("Array {:?}", array);
}
```

Comment: Воу воу) Удалить элемент я могу в произвольной форме. Но самая оптимальная форма это удаления С КОНЦА, тогда происходит обычная операция len -= 1;   А то что вы предлагаете это даже не решение моего вопроса))

Comment: Требуется: удалить элемент из Vec с возвратом результата. Существует функция remove в Vec, но она не возвращяет Option в случае не успеха, а заставляет программу падать.

Программа падает - нет, возвращение результата? - это в виде bool ? 

Что вы хотите этим сказать, если сами разобрались? я вас не понимаю